# Horizontal Grid stretching based on width of only some child elements

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm implementing a strikethrough effect on an app using a white line. It's infuriating that MS haven't just provided a a strikethrough text effect, but there you go.

Regardless of the lenght of my text, the line stretches to the width of the screen. How do I set the grid to only stretch to the width of the text? is there a way?

Here's my current XAML

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" FontSize="28" Margin="60,0,0,0">
    </TextBlock>
    <Line Opacity="{Binding LineOpacity}" Stretch="Fill" 
        Visibility="{Binding IsComplete}" Stroke="White" 
        StrokeThickness="4" X1="1" Width="Auto" Margin="60,5,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Rectangle instead of a Line would do the job:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="60,0,0,0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" FontSize="28"/>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Height="4" Fill="White"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: that only works for static text. With dynamic binding it returns 0 for the `ActualWidth` of `textBlock`